# collectionview just filling one cell

Tags: ios, xcode, collectionview

I'm trying to fill a collectionview with data from an array which I've checked it has the data, but at runtime it's filling just the cell at index 0.

The collectionview is a list of friends in pages of 9 items showing photo and name. The number of items at section is working properly, I mean, if the array has 3 objects, the collectionview displays three cells but just the first one with the photo and name of the object, concretly the last one in the array, not the first one. And the other cells show the prototype cell.

I guess I'm dealing wrong with the indexpath of the collection view, but I have another one in my storyboard and works properly. This other one has only one cell per page, could be something related to this?

I paste my collectionview methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
     return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.miListaAmigos count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendCell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:102];
nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:12.0];
nameLabel.text = [[self.miListaAmigos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"usr_username"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try to log `[[self.miListaAmigos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"usr_username"];` Are they sometimes blank?

Comment: `nameLabel` is in `self.view` or in `cell`?

Comment: Right Chinttu, it in cell, copy-paste issue... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you not directly reuse `UILabel` from  self.view, `UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:102];`

try this below code for solve your problem:

```
   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
      //Create UILabel here
      UILabel *nameLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 20)];
    nameLabel.tag=100;
     [cell addSubview:nameLabel];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:12.0];
    }

    // Access label and reuse 
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    nameLabel.text = [[self.miListaAmigos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"usr_username"];

    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I think that check should be `if ([cell viewWithTag:100] == nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Check your collectionView alloc and required deleagte:

UICollectionViewDelegate、UICollectionViewDataSource、 UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

e.g.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[collectionLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:collectionLayout];
[collectionView registerClass:[CNCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIndetify];
collectionView.delegate = self;
collectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:collectionView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your label is in `self.view` not in the `cell`... You really should make a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`

File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class

- Class:           MYFriendCollectionViewCell
- Subclass of:     UICollectionViewCell
- Also Create XIB: Tick
- Language:        Objective C

Look at MYFriendCollectionViewCell.xib and make your label inside here... connect the labels to an `IBOutlet`... don't use tags...

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GusRijNLUGg <- connecting IBOutlets

Add the line below in your `ViewController`

`[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MYFriendCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`

Change your `cellForItem` to:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendCell";

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MYFriendCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.font = nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:12.0]; // This ideally would be in MYFriendCollectionViewCell.m 
    cell.nameLabel.text = [[self.miListaAmigos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"usr_username"];

    return cell;
}
```